# Laravel Eloquent - orderBy column find in related model

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

**INFORMATIONS**

Database

```
events        | id | to_user_id    | from_user_id |
event_details | id | event_id      | when         |
```

Event.php

```
class Event extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'events';

public function event_detail() {
    return $this->hasOne('EventDetail');
}}
```

EventDetail.php

```
class EventDetail extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'event_details';

public function event() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Event', 'event_id');
}}
```

**QUESTION**

I want to get all events (Event model) and order by 'when' column in related EventDetail model. I wrote a query and it works:

```
$event = Event::join('event_details as p', 'p.event_id', '=', 'event.id')
                    ->orderBy('p.when', 'asc')
                    ->select('events.*')
                    ->with('event_detail')
                    ->get();
```

but when i would like to add `->where('to_user_id', '=', 0)` clause i get error. **How can I fix it?**

Moreover I want to know **if this query is correct with good practise?** 
Can you write it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, had to recreate your project/tables
All tests are running correctly but I have noticed a few things you may consider changing.

```
$events = Event::with(['event_detail'=> function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('when', 'asc');
}])
->where('to_user_id', 0)
->get();
```

Also your code may be better if you have an Event

```
public function event_detail(){
    //considering you will have multiples? or just the one event detail?
    return $this->hasMany('EventDetail');
}
```

As you can see, the one event I stored has 2 event details & they are all ordered by ASC.
[image]

You can use the other method that doesnt utilize 'with()' but I prefer it. Very nice for json results where you can daisychain a lot of related models.

Hope this helps

Comment: After editing... again looks like it should work, but orderBy does not work :-(

Comment: Its nice you're looking for better was of coding. I can admire that :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this query. I should add `->where('events.to_user_id', '=', 0)` so

```
$event = Event::join('event_details as p', 'p.event_id', '=', 'event.id')
                ->orderBy('p.when', 'asc')
                ->select('events.*')
                ->where('events.to_user_id', '=', 0)
                ->with('event_detail')
                ->get();
```

However, I would like to know if this query is correct with good practise? **Can you write it better?**